# how to change 2147483647 as original mobile number

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

in my database having register table users can register in our project we are able to insert all the value...for registration form having mobile number so in database for moblie number i have given datatype as int(24) so mobile number saved as 2147483647....so then i changed to bigint(datatype) then now im able to save mobile number as original number...here the problem is the before change of datatype mobile number is not changed to original number how should i get the original number please give an idea or senario for the process to do....how should i get original numbers.
(2147483647 to 9999999999)...

Comment: This is *really* unclear.  But it sounds like you were using a datatype that was too small for your data.  If so, then obviously there's no way to get the original data back.

Comment: Also, note that phone numbers are not integers; you should some sort of string type to store them.

Comment: To give an example of Oli's comment: `0123123123` and `123123123` are different phone numbers, but any number field will treat them identically.

Answer (score 6):

You can't. You didn't store the original data anywhere so it is lost.

Answer (score 5):

You can't recover your original data.

The reason is because the maximum value for signed integer is `2147483647`. Even if you have specify `INT(24)` that doesn't mean that you can store up length of 24 because the maximum allowable value is `2147483647`. The meaning of `24` in `INT` declaration is the length of padded zero and is only applicable if `ZEROFILL` is enabled on the column. But still the length cannot reach up to `24` characters.

If you have save the original data as `9152667253`, it will be truncated into the maximum value of `2147483647`.